"Discrepancy" just as "difference" or "difference between accounts"?

Additionally, Black Codes regulated how freedmen were allowed to navigate their lives. These codes predictably gave them fewer freedoms than white people enjoyed. This discrepancy is inherently undemocratic as democracy relies on equal treatment.

When describing the difference in treatment between white people and black people during the Reconstruction Era, my friend used the word "discrepancy" and I pointed out that discrepancy is a non-standard or potentially even wrong way to describe what's going on there.
After a quick round of googling she insists that the common definition "a lack of compatibility or similarity between two or more facts." supports her position. Cambridge is closer to what I think of as a discrepancy, it says "a difference between two things that should be the same" but that kind of doesn't help my case either.
To me, a discrepancy is about accounts, recollections, narratives, etc., not about comparing two independent pieces of data against each other and finding what is just a difference. I suggested using "disparity", for her use case, but we're still trying to figure out what is correct.

How did your friend actually use "discrepancy", what was the actual sentence? It's difficult to know if it was used incorrectly when we don't know how it was used.

I edited the post to include the context, thank you for the hint.

One of the differences between discrepancy and disparity is that discrepancy usually has a tight focus, getting down to detailed facts. Disparity is handy for more general imbalances. Since they have referenced codified freedoms, discrepancy seems perfectly fine.

"discrepancy" also has a negative implication, while "difference" is neutral. This makes "discrepancy" more appropriate when talking about the effects of racism.

I'd take the CD definition as the default: 'a difference between two things that should be the same'. This may be in recorded data (eg on a balance sheet) or behaviour / make-up of a natural system, it doesn't have to have a moral content.

The fact that the OP hesitates between two terms, does not make it a matter of opinion. I think that determining which term is more appropriate for a particular context is very pertinent on this site. Please do not close the question.

Yes, you compare two things, they are different, and should be same.

Since the message of your passage seems to point more to the unfairness of the matter (inherently undemocratic as democracy relies on equal treatment), I would say that disparity is more accurate here. It makes you also think about discrimination. Cambridge defines it as:

a lack of equality or similarity, especially in a way that is not fair:

the growing disparity between rich and poor


Discrepancy is not wrong either, but it focuses more on the unexpectedness of the difference:

an unexpected difference, esp. in two amounts or two sets of facts or conditions, which suggests that something is wrong and has to be explained:

There were troubling discrepancies between his public and private opinions on how to balance the budget.


Even the examples provided for the two words show with which categories disparity is more commonly used. But at the end of the day, it is a matter of choice, depending on what you want to stress more.

Another consideration is that discrepancy often implies a comparison to an accepted norm. Implying white freedoms were the norm for comparison may not be entirely PC in an academic situation, although this is being very fussy with the words. Disparity doesn't invoke the idea of a fixed reference for comparison in the same way.

Both are applicable. The discrepancy in the freedoms between white and black people, which, in turn is a disparity.
